# Powershell Sort-Object PSCustomObject with Object[] as value

Tags: powershell, sort-object

I am using RestAPI access to azure. I am getting a list of changesets for a build ID.

I would like to sort the object type with increasing Changeset number.

The type I receive for `$changeset.GetType()`:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

This is the output `$changeset`:

```
count value
----- -----
   50 {@{id=68.......
```

Therefore, I checked the type of value `$changeset.value.GetType()`:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

And afterwards I checked the type of an element:

```
$changeset.value[0].GetType():

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

I did try `Sort-Object` with ascending and descending, but it does not change the order:

```
$changeset = $changeset | sort-object { $_.value.id } -desc
```

I would like to keep the structure as it is to not break something. There are lots of properties within the component.

Comment: To clarify, you want to sort on the property `id`? Are you able to export the object using `Export-CliXml` and share it with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an example working dataset, it's hard create an absolute working solution for your use case, however you could sort the data using the below:

```
$changeset | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value | Sort-Object -Property id
```

This would return all of the objects under the immediate property `value` and sorted on the property `id`.

Comment: Thanks, that did work fine. I tried to select the innercomponent only in Sort-Object without success. I would have tried your solution anyway, if it would not have worked directly. The original structure was changed, but I will handle this. Now value array is lost, but I can access the components without value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain the object as a whole with its present structure:

```
$changeset.value = @($changeset.value | Sort-Object -Descending -Property Id)
```

That is:

- You must apply the [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) call to the `.value` property, which contains the array of `[pscustomobject]` instances you want to sort by their `.Id` property values.
- Enclosing the command in `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), ensures that the sort objects are treated as an array, even if situationally only *one* object may be present.
- Assigning the results back to `$changeset.value` replaces the original array with a new, sorted array.